# Make the content of a checkbox listview item clickable to activate the checkbox

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm populating a listview with checkbox listview items.  Currently the only way to check the box is by clicking on just the box.  How can I extend this to make the content of the listview item activate the checkbox also

```
           <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2"
                  IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding Value}" ContentTemplate="{Binding FilterValueTemplate, ElementName=Q_ROOT}"/>
```

Above was in my theming, below is the actual view.

```
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                    
                <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ListViewItem}}">
                    <CheckBox.Content>
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Value}" ContentTemplate="{Binding FilterValueTemplate, ElementName=QFSP_ROOT}"/>
                    </CheckBox.Content>
                </CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: You could add a SelectedItem binding in the viewmodel, and a mousedown event that will change the selected item checkbox IsChecked. sounds right?

Comment: i could, but that seems like a hack i shouldnt have to do.  There has to be a way here in the xaml to bind it.

Comment: Well, if you are trying to bind a property like IsSelected, than I guess xaml is all that you need. If you want to bind a mouse gesture and rather do it mvvm -no code behind you could route the event to the viewmodel.

Answer (score 1):

Bind **`IsChecked`** with **`IsSelected`** property of ListViewItem using **`RelativeSource`** :

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                              Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"/>
```

Comment: is saying mode and ancestortype arent found in type relative source

Comment: Doing this doesnt seem to change anything.  Still cant click on the content.

Comment: @Mertis - I am not sure how you have tried it because it works when `CheckBox` is defined within `ItemTemplate` of ListView. Can you add more code to your question where you are defining this checkBox?

Comment: I changed the actual view to have what you show, the checking part of the box works now, but the uncheck doesnt.

Comment: My 2nd block of code i have in my question is what is now allowing me to check and uncheck the box, but now what this is tied to (a table filter) is no longer working.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the content presenter content inside the checkbox itself and it now works fine:

```
<CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" 
     Content="{Binding Value}" ContentTemplate="{Binding FilterValueTemplate, ElementName=QFSP_ROOT}"/>
```